# git on WSL strange behavior cloning repositories on external drives

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I come up with quite a strange behavior with git on WSL, if I want to clone a repo on an external drive, e.g.:

`git clone git@github.com:Me/Myrepo.git`,

I get:

```
fatal: Unable to create temporary file '/mnt/d/Myrepo/.git/objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission denied
remote: Enumerating objects: 20537, done.
fatal: index-pack failed`
```

That problem only occurs, if I try to clone on my external SSD (cloning on a local drive works just fine).
Do I overlook something, or how is that explainable?

Comment: "Permission denied" means what it says: Git tried to create a file, and your OS denied permission for Git to create that file. You'll need to consult the OS documentation to see why it's denying that permission to you (probably something to do with permissions, and perhaps ownership).

Comment: Is that external drive being automounted by WSL or are you mounting it manually?